# Evaluate $\int \int_{S} \vec {F} \cdot \vec {n} ds$ for $\vec {F} = x \vec{i} - y \vec {j} + (z^{2} - 1) \vec {k}$

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

Evaluate $\int \int_{S} \vec {F} \cdot \vec{n} ds$ for $\vec {F} = x \vec{i} - y \vec {j} + (z^{2} - 1) \vec {k}$ where $S$ is the surface bounded by the cylinder $x^{2} + y^{2} = 4$ and the planes $z = 0$ and $z = 1$.

My Attempt:
Let $\phi = x^{2} + y^{2} - 4$ then
$$\textrm {grad} (\phi) = \nabla \phi = 2x \vec{i} + 2y \vec {j}$$
$$|\textrm {grad} (\phi) | = \sqrt{4x^2 + 4y^2} $$
$$= \sqrt{4(x^2 + y^2)}$$
$$= \sqrt{4 * 4} = 4$$
Then the unit normal vector
$$\vec {n} = \frac {\textrm {grad} (\phi)}{|\textrm {grad} (\phi) |}$$
$$ = \frac { x \vec{i} + y \vec{j}}{2}$$
We then have:
$$\vec {F} . \vec {n} = \frac {x^2 - y^2}{2}$$

How to proceed from here?

Comment: From the wording of your post it's unclear - you have the cylinder portion down, but the unit normal will change on the ends, you will have to do that calculation again. I'm always happy to see people remembering that gradients are orthogonal to level surfaces!

Comment: From here, note that $$F\cdot n(x,y,z)dS = -F\cdot n(y,x,z)dS$$ What conclusion can you draw from this relationship and the symmetry of the cylindrical surface? Then what is the integral through the ends of the cylinder at the planes?

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from where you stopped,

$i$) Outward flux through cylindrical surface

You found $\vec {F} . \hat {n} = \frac {x^2 - y^2}{2}$

Please note the symmetry of the region about $z$-axis and that the integral of $x^2$ will be same as the integral of $y^2$. That leads to flux through the cylindrical surface being zero. Considering that was not the case, you could set it up in cylindrical coordinates using parametrization $x = 2 \cos\theta, y = 2 \sin\theta$.

The integral to find flux can be written as,

$ \displaystyle \iint_S  (\vec F \cdot \hat n) ~ ds =  \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{4 \cos2\theta}{2} \cdot 2 ~ dz ~ d\theta = 0$

$ii$) Based on the wording of the question, it suggests the surface includes the bottom and top discs at $z = 0$ and $z = 1$. If so,

For the top surface at $z = 1, \vec F = (x, - y, 0)$

The outward normal vector is $(0, 0, 1)$ and hence $\vec F \cdot \hat n = 0$. So the flux through the top disc is zero.

For the bottom disc surface at $z = 0, \vec F = (x, - y, -1)$ and outward normal vector is $(0, 0, -1)$ so,

$\vec F \cdot \hat n = 1$ so the flux is simply equal to the surface area of the disc, which is $4 \pi$.

---

If the surface includes top and bottom discs, you could have applied divergence theorem easily as well. As we have a closed surface, the outward flux through the closed surface is equivalent to the volume integral of the divergence of the vector field.

Here, $\nabla \cdot \vec F = 2 z$

Flux $ = \displaystyle \iiint_{V} (\nabla \cdot \vec F) ~ dV = \int_0^1 4 \pi \cdot 2 z ~ dz = 4 \pi$

Comment: How did you calculate the outward normal vectors as $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,0,-1)$? Please elaborate.

Comment: @pi-π Take top disc. It is in the plane $z = 1$. The normal vector to this plane is parallel to z-axis and so the upward pointing unit vector is $(0, 0, 1)$. Another way to see - we know that the normal vector to the plane $ax + b + cz = d$ is $(a, b, c)$ and that is how we get $(0, 0, 1)$. The same is true for the plane $z = 0$ but we want a downward pointing vector at $z = 0$ and hence $(0, 0, -1)$.

Comment: @pi-π let me know if this is clear and if you have any other questions